# Send Text Message To All Contacts

Tags: android, sms

I need to send a text message to everyone on a phone. I have developed an Android application that sends a SMS to contacts, but I'm not sure how to do it for all contacts, especially since the phone I have to do it with doesn't have any mobile plan. Should I develop an Android application, or is there a better way of doing this? I have also tried putting all of the contacts in a group, but I can only send a message to ten people. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you want to send sms without a mobile plan?

Comment: Unfortunately thats what I'm trying to figure out how to do. Is there a website that does that?